# How to safely convert 120VAC from a lamp bulb socket to 12VDC

Tags: ac, adapter

For the holidays, I'd like to make my chandelier light up with different colors.  There are all sorts of cheap RGB LED strips that, via remote, allow the user to program patterns of lights.

These strips can require 12VDC @ 6A, and I'm not sure how to get DC power at a remote location like a chandelier.

My idea was to replace one of the lights in my chandelier with *something* that magically converts the AC to 12VDC.  The only thing I was able to find were E27 to GU10 converters.  This is *close*, as I could simply wire a 12VDC converter into it.

*But is it safe*?

Are there any other safety-related things to consider when undertaking a project like this?  Since 72W (12V @ 6A) is below the maximum rating for the bulb, hopefully I am okay there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if they make AC adapters that screw into light sockets.  I would suggest finding a small wall wart that will provide the necessary voltage and current and a separate light bulb socket adapter that you can plug it in to.

Comment: so basically, what I have shown in my question, but just (safely) connect wires to the AC connections and feed them to a normal DC converter?

Comment: If you get one with bare leads instead of a plug, then you can do that.  Otherwise, I would recommend something like this: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001PCVTFC .

Comment: @Dave keep in mind that you have to account for the total fixture wattage limit and the circuit limit. Also, 12v 6A adapters arn't exactly small. On the size of medium to large laptop bricks.

Comment: Possibly you could put the adapter in the ceiling void above the rose, then route the ELV through the existing wire (check that it is 6A rated).

Comment: @PeteKirkham He just wants to replace one bulb, not the whole fixture.  And I think the idea is to make it temporary.

Comment: Correct, this is just a temporary thing.  Probably the biggest issue right now is that the chandelier is on a dimmer, so I'll probably need to change out the switch.  The 12V/6A power adapter I picked up from amazon is astonishingly small, just like any other I've used before: http://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Power-Supply-LCD-Monitor/dp/B003TUMDWG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386914456&sr=8-1&keywords=12v+6a.  The power rating I was quoting was for a single light bulb, which is 1/6 the total wattage of the chandelier.